# Override GD star rating IP based restrictions

Tags: plugin-gd-star-rating

Anyone know if its possible to prevent [GD star rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/) from logging the IP address of a user's machine? I realise this is intended to stop people rating more than once but it prevents people from being able to rate if they are behind a proxy.

A couple of thoughts which come to mind:

- override the method which does the logging in my theme's `functions.php`
- do something at the web-server level to mask the IP (potentially fatal probably)

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for this in the article rating settings. I was using thumbs so hadn't spotted it.

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed. I just want to point out that even though this setting is under the "Article Stars" tab, it affects voting on "Article Thumbs" as well